# Best way to use both passed props and theme props to resolve in styled component literals?

Tags: typescript, styled-components

This works but looks pretty contrived:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

interface StrapLineProps {
    children: any;
    variant?: 'light';
}

export default function StrapLine(props: StrapLineProps) {
    const StrapLineDiv = styled.span`
        ${providedProps => `
            ${props.variant === 'light' && `
                color: ${providedProps.theme.lightTextColor};
            `}
        `}
    `;

    return (
        <StrapLineDiv>
            {props.children}
        </StrapLineDiv>
    );
}
```

**Is there a better way than to use both provided theme props and passed props in a Typescript project?**

Here is an alternative I have tried that looks nicer but causes the error

> [ts] Parameter 'providedProps' implicitly has an 'any' type.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

interface StrapLineProps {
    children: any;
    variant?: 'light';
}

export default function StrapLine(props: StrapLineProps) {
    const StrapLineDiv = styled.span`
        ${props.variant === 'light' && `
            color: ${providedProps => providedProps.theme.lightTextColor};
        `}
    `;

    return (
        <StrapLineDiv>
            {props.children}
        </StrapLineDiv>
    );
}
```

Here is another alternative I have tried that looks nicer but causes the error

> [ts] Property 'variant' does not exist on type
>   'ThemedStyledProps,
>   HTMLSpanElement>, any>'.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

interface StrapLineProps {
    children: any;
    variant?: 'light';
}

export default function StrapLine(props: StrapLineProps) {
    const StrapLineDiv = styled.span`
        ${providedProps => providedProps.variant === 'light' && `
            color: ${providedProps.theme.lightTextColor};
        `}
    `;

    return (
        <StrapLineDiv>
            {props.children}
        </StrapLineDiv>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's unnecessary to create a class, with Typescript you can just pass your types props in your styled component like that :

```
 import styled from 'styled-components'

 interface StrapLineProps {
     children: any;
     variant?: string;
 }

 const StrapLineDiv = styled.span<StrapLineProps>`
      color: ${({variant, theme}) => variant === 'light' ? theme.lightTextColor : 'blue'};   
 `;

 StrapLineDiv.defaultProps = {
     variant: 'light'
 }

 export default StrapLineDiv
```

and in an another file when you use it you can just do like :

`AnotherFile.tsx`

```
render() {
    return(
        <StrapLineDiv>
            /* What you want */
        </StrapLineDiv>
    ) 
}
```